# Calculate the percent difference between two percentages at two dates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The goal is to create a column that shows the percent difference between to percentages.

**Tried creating many calculated fields around**

-first() - last() -- this just calculates the week number difference

-if date = #2019-02-03# then sum number of records else null end -- invalid

-case when date = #2019-02-03# then sum number of records else null end -- invalid

The 'filter 1' column is where I'd like to display this information.

**Expected result:**
row 1 in filter 1 should = 12% (absolute percentage change of -5 and 7)

[image]

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: what is the criteria to decide start date and end date

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out in two ways:
one created two date fields - one for one week and one for the last week
: then made a diff % measure and used these as the columns.

There's another way, more gnarly:

```
if first() == 0 then
(
window_sum((if last() == 0 then sum(count_measure) end))
-(window_sum(if first()==0 then sum(count_measure) end))
)
/(window_sum(if first()==0 then sum(count_measure) end))
end
```